# roslaunch turtlebot_gazebo failure

Tags: ros, roslaunch, turtlebot-gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After Synaptic installation of ros-indigo-rocon and kabuki, I downloaded the turtlebot.rosinstall and did a rosdep install.
next I added the source to .bashrc and executed.
Then,

```
~/turtlebot$ sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-turtlebot ros-indigo-turtlebot-apps ros-indigo-turtlebot-interactions ros-indigo-turtlebot-simulator ros-indigo-kobuki-ftdi ros-indigo-rocon-remocon
```

My next command was:

```
:~/turtlebot$ roslaunch turtlebot_gazebo turtlebot_empty_world.launch 

[turtlebot_empty_world.launch] is neither a launch file in package [turtlebot_gazebo] nor is [turtlebot_gazebo] a launch file name 
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file**
```

When I reran the installation, I got:

```
ros-indigo-kobuki-ftdi is already the newest version. 
ros-indigo-rocon-remocon is already the newest version. 
ros-indigo-turtlebot is already the newest version. 
ros-indigo-turtlebot-apps is already the newest version. 
ros-indigo-turtlebot-interactions is already the newest version. 
ros-indigo-turtlebot-simulator is already the newest version. 
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 215 not upgraded.
```

Can anyone suggest what I should do to recover?

What is the log file referred to in the error message?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/223792/roslaunch-turtlebot_gazebo-failure/) by [ptreyesguy](https://answers.ros.org/users/25433/ptreyesguy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2016-01-11

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [marwa eldiwiny](https://answers.ros.org/users/27638/marwa-eldiwiny/) on 2016-08-05**:
Me to I get the same error

[turtlebot_gazebo.launch] is neither a launch file in package [turtlebot_example] nor is [turtlebot_example] a launch file name
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should use this command:

```
roslaunch turtlebot_gazebo turtlebot_world.launch
```

There are some tutorials at http://wiki.ros.org/action/show/Robots/TurtleBot?distro=indigo in section 6 about bringing up the TurtleBot in gazebo.

---

Originally posted by [nampi](https://answers.ros.org/users/24910/nampi/) with karma: 77 on 2016-01-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ptreyesguy](https://answers.ros.org/users/25433/ptreyesguy/) on 2016-01-11**:
Thank you nampi but using the command you specify does not work. I get the same error message again:
**[turtlebot_world] is neither a launch file in package [turtlebot_gazebo] nor is [turtlebot_gazebo] a launch file name
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file

**Comment by [nampi](https://answers.ros.org/users/24910/nampi/) on 2016-01-11**:
@ptreyesguy Try to type "roslaunch turtlebot_gazebo" in command line, then press 'Tab'. What launch files do you have?

**Comment by [ptreyesguy](https://answers.ros.org/users/25433/ptreyesguy/) on 2016-01-11**:
**No result from Tab but "dpkg -l |grep gazebo" shows:
ros-indigo- followed by, respectively
gazebo2m concert-service-gazebo, indigo-gazebo-concert,gazebo-msgs, gazebo-plugins, gazebo-ros, gazebo-ros-control, gazebo-ros-pkgs, kabuki-gazebo-plugins, turtlebot-gazebo

**Comment by [nampi](https://answers.ros.org/users/24910/nampi/) on 2016-01-12**:
I have some of these packages and in addition I have "gazebo2", "ros-indigo-kobuki-gazebo" in output "dpkg -l | grep gazebo".

**Comment by [ptreyesguy](https://answers.ros.org/users/25433/ptreyesguy/) on 2016-01-12**:
nampi:
Please tell me where your packages are, relative to HOME.

**Comment by [nampi](https://answers.ros.org/users/24910/nampi/) on 2016-01-14**:
My packages are situated here: /opt/ros/indigo/share. Also you can use command: "roscd". roscd allows you to change directories using a package name. Read more here http://wiki.ros.org/rosbash#roscd.